# Hadoop error, UnknownHostException

Tags: hadoop

I'm new to Hadoop so as to Ubuntu. I've installed hadoop for a project but I have an exception with NameNode.

When I type the following command in terminal:

```
hadoop fs -mkdir /WordCountTutorial
```

I get the following exception :

```
-mkdir: java.net.UnknownHostException: NameNode
Usage: hadoop fs [generic options] -mkdir [-p] <path> ...
```

I've read that I have to look for the domain name in the configuration files and replace it by "localhost", but as I mentioned I'm new in hadoop and I don't know in which file to look for it.
Any help ?

My hadoop version:

```
Hadoop 2.7.5
Subversion https://shv@git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop.git -r 18065c2b6806ed4aa6a3187d77cbe21bb3dba075
Compiled by kshvachk on 2017-12-16T01:06Z
Compiled with protoc 2.5.0
From source with checksum 9f118f95f47043332d51891e37f736e9
This command was run using /home/hadoop1/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.7.5.jar
```

Comment: Does -ls is working for you? try    "hadoop fs -ls /"

Comment: @Vivek I get the following message:
18/05/08 17:12:07 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
-ls: java.net.UnknownHostException: NameNode
Usage: hadoop fs [generic options] -ls [-d] [-h] [-R] [<path> ...]

Comment: It means, your Hadoop is not configured properly. So, first configure the Hadoop, you can refer this link:    https://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/                     . Am sure you missed something while configring the Hadoop.

Comment: *I don't know in which file to look for it*, Change it in `core-site.xml`.

Comment: *replace it by localhost* -- Actually, no, you replace it with the FQDN of the server running the service

Answer (score 1):

it  may caused by hosts file  setting problem
in this file  `/etc/hosts` 
add your ${ip} ${hostname} at last line  with `vi` command

save &exit;

then  restart your network  and reformat  your  hdfs
with this command

```
hadoop namenode -format
```